# Run UI Tests using Selenium (WebDriver) as different user

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run UI Tests using selenium (WebDriver) as different user.

```
string[] rolesArray = {"Admin", "Manager"};
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("ik\adam.walas@com.pl"), rolesArray);
```

I put these code inside constructor `WebDriver`. However when I run single UI Test using Visual Studio, the test runs as a user who is logged on computer so my account. How can I solve this issue? I use `Chrome` as a browser for UI Tests. Should I use selenium chromedriver with `ChromeOptions` to workaround this?

Comment: To ensure clean and isolated sessions, you are recommended to use chromedriver and to disable all extensions , you have to use chromeOptions.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh can you give me some example or reference to this issue about chromedriver with chromeoptions? Also how to disable all extensions?